# migration fails in Rails with some SQL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

rake db:migrate is failing on my developement server, the error is:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for
 at line 1: {:username=>"user", :password=>"user"}D:/WorkSpace/Ruby_WorkSPace/SLA_Rails_june10/db/migrate/20130611053608
d:in `migrate'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My migration code is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.column :username , :string 
      t.column :password , :string
    end
    User.create :username=>"user" ,:password=>"user"
    User.create :username=>"admin" ,:password=>"admin"
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end

enter code here
```

my model code is

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :password
end
```

Comment: Your migration class most definitely should not be named identically to your `User` model.

Comment: @Deefour : if I remove the User.create line , then it works fine creating the table

Comment: I'm just pointing out why you're having the issue you're asking about. The migration will run within without the model instantiation because you're no longer referring to class methods that don't exist.

Comment: @Deefour : so can i name the migration class "Users" from User ??

Comment: I suggest reading the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-migration) on the topic. Your migration should be more appropriately named `CreateUsers` or similar. As it stands your `User` migration class is in a naming conflict with your `User` model class.

Comment: this migration class is autogenerated by the command 
script/ generate migration users

Comment: have you tried seeds ?

Answer (score 0):

Migration code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.column :username , :string 
      t.column :password , :string
    end
    User.create :username=>"user", :password=>"user"
    User.create :username=>"admin",:password=>"admin"
  end

  def self.down
     drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Model code:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :username, :password
 end
```

In the code above, you are creating two users, while creating table.

Rails has a 'seeds' feature that should be used for seeding a database with initial data. It's a really simple feature: just fill up `db/seeds.rb` with some Ruby code, and `run rake db:seed`

So you just remove the create statements and your migration code should be like this:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def self.up
     create_table :users do |t|
       t.column :username , :string 
       t.column :password , :string
     end
    end

   def self.down
     drop_table :users
   end
 end
```

After creating the table, just fill your `db/seeds.rb` to feed database table:

user = [{:username=>"user", :password => "user"}, {:username=>"admin", :password => "admin"}]

User.create(user)

Then run:
`rake db:seed`

Answer (score 0):

Use the rails command to create migration scripts:

```
rails g scaffold User username:string password:string
```

That command will generate the following script. Then you can add "seeds".

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :password

      t.timestamps
    end
    User.create(:username=>"user", :password=>"user")
    User.create(:username=>"admin", :password=>"admin")
  end
end
```

By the way, note that the initial data should be located in db/seeds.rb

Comment: dont wanna use scaffolding